# Truncated Buffer

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to troubleshoot a strange C programming problem.

I'm entering a URL on a client program and then transferring that URL to a server program. The only issue is, that when the server program receives the URL it's missing it's first two characters. So, if the url is http://www.google.com what the server reports is receiving is "tp://www.google.com."

The weird thing is that it's not some partial send problem. I'm checking on the number of bytes sent and it's claiming that the entire message is sent. The issue is that on the receiving end it's only claiming that it's getting a small chunk of the data. The receiver reports back that it's received the message length -2. Here is the code on the receiving end:

```
  printf("%s \n", "Connected. Receive length of URL to wget.");
  if ((messageSize = recv(acceptDescriptor, &urlLength, sizeof (int), 0)) == -1) {
    perror("recv URL length");
    exit(1);
  }
  urlSizeInt = atoi(urlLength);
  char url[urlSizeInt];
  printf("%s %d \n", "urlSizeInt: ", urlSizeInt);
  printf("%s \n", "Receive URL to wget.");

  if((messageSize = recv(acceptDescriptor, &url, 13, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("recv URL");
    exit(1);
  }
```

Sending code:

```
  printf("%s \n", "Connected");
  //connected to first stepping stone in the chain.
  //transfer the length of the URL
  if (send(socketDescriptor, urlLengthStr, strlen(urlLengthStr), 0) == -1){
    perror("send URL Length");
    exit(0);
  }

  //transfer the URL
  printf("%s %d \n", "strenlen(url): ",strlen(url));
  printf("%s %s \n", "url: ",url);
  int sent;
  int totalSent=0;
  if((sent=send(socketDescriptor, url, strlen(url), 0))==-1){
      perror("send URL");
      exit(0);
    }

  printf("%s %d \n", "sent: ",sent);


Send Output:
Connected
strenlen(url):  13
url:  http://www.cs
sent:  13

Receive Output:
Connected. Receive length of URL to wget.
urlSizeInt:  13
Receive URL to wget.
messageSize:  11
URL Received:  tp://www.cs
```

Code to encode the length as a char for sending:

```
char* url = "http://www.cs";
int urlLength  = strlen(url);
char* urlLengthStr;
sprintf(urlLengthStr, "%d", urlLength);
```

Comment: What's the code on the sending end?

Comment: Updated the description. Keep in mind that if the length of the URL is 13 bytes then sent will report that it has sent 13 bytes. So it's not sending a truncated message.

Comment: run it through charles proxy or wireshark or something so you can really see what is being sent.

Comment: Why are you trying to "recv" a length when your sending code doesn't appear to send one?

Comment: I send a length and it's received properly.

Comment: @natediggs From what I see your length receiving code is broken, even if it gives the right answer. *Please* show the length *sending* code, or I'm unable to help further.

Comment: As an aside, you never `malloc` any memory to hold the urlLengthStr so the sprintf will either fail or corrupt memory somewhere else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for posting the full code. the problem lies in the way you send the UrlLength. Because you always `recv` `sizeof(int)` bytes, your first read is consuming the first bytes of the sent URL.

Start from the beginning - assume you don't send the URL Length.

**Problem** : URLs are variable length. How can the receiver know when it's read it all?
**Solution** : Send the length before

This is fine, unless you encode the length as a string, because that introduces another problem

**Problem** : The URL length may be variable length ("1", "12","1234"). How can the receiver know when it's read it all?
**Solution** : Haven't we been here before somewhere...

There are a couple of ways out of this recursive problem:

Solution a : Encode the URL length as a fixed size field. (you can just send the binary representation of an int, although beware of byte ordering problems - or you could encode it as a fixed-width ascii field , e.g, "00000124"

TX (ignoring byte ordering issues mentioned by JimR)

```
  int urlLength = strlen(url);
  send(socketDescriptor, &urlLength, sizeof(int), 0)
```

RX:

```
  int urlLength;
  recv(socketDescriptor, &urlLength, sizeof(int), 0)
```

Solution b: Use a termination character (often null, or linefeed) to indicate the end of the URL. Just read bytes in a loop until the terminator is reached. This also solves the 'partial recv' problem you would otherwise encounter.

Comment: The "length" I send across is a integer I encode as a char and send across. I use atoi to turn it back into an int on the receiving end. It is being sent and received properly.

Comment: @natediggs. When you recv the "length", you *always* read four bytes from the socket, because `sizeof(int) == 4` (assuming 32-bit ints). If you're "encoding it as a char" how is that happening, and how many bytes are being sent?

Comment: I guess I don't totally understand. I send two buffers. One buffer is urlLength which contains the length and the second is url which contains the actual URL. Why would the first send take up the first two bytes of the buffer if I'm doing two separate sends and two separate receives?

Comment: @natediggs. It's just a *stream* of data. The gaps between sends are not detectable by the receiver. Four sends of one byte each is identical to one send of four bytes.

Comment: OK, so even though the first two bytes containing the length have been read then that doesn't mean they're empty? So when I send I have to send all in one stream?

Comment: @natediggs - With TCP you need a way of encoding your data so that indvidual elements can be separated. If my url is "stackoverflow.com" and I just put the length as a string in front, I get "17stackoverflow.com" How do you separate the length from the url? (especially if the url was "3com.com")

Comment: OK, I've got you. When I send the length it's going on the beginning of the buffer. So it's setting at buffer+0 and buffer+1. Then, when I send the URL it's sitting at buffer+2->strlen(url). So I need to read buffer+sizeoflength to get the first two characters in the stream. Is there any way to clear the buffer between sends? Thank you for al your help by the way.

Answer (score 0):

When you're reading from a socket, you're reading a stream, not a file.
See [here](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html) for good guidelines for writing network code.

Even though the sending side may have sent all the data at once, that does not guarantee that you will see all the data at once.  You have to loop on `recv`, taking into account the number of bytes received for each call.  If `recv` returns `0` the socket was closed or there was an error and you will receive no more data from that socket.

With those things in mind... Kinda sorta pseudo code, I didn't test this, but hope it gives you the idea:

```
int expectedLength = readLengthFromSocket( socket, sizeof( int ) );
int bytesRead = 0;
char buffer[expectedLength];
bytesRead = recv( socket, buffer, ... );
runningLength = 0;
if( bytesRead < 1 )
    // Socket closed or there was an error, handle that here
else
{    runningLength += bytesRead;
     while( runningLength < expectedLength )
     {
         bytesRead = recv( socket, buffer + runningLength, ... );
         if( bytesRead < 1 )
            // Socket closed or there was an error, handle that here
            break;
         else
             runningLength += bytesRead;
     }
}
```

Note that reading and writing `int`, `long`, `long long`, `short` and the unsigned variants over the network typically require byte swapping.  Reading a buffer of bytes does not.

See [here](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html) for an explanation.